# Unable to load the "Craft\xyz" runtime after Craft update

Tags: templating, updating, twigextension

After updating from Craft CMS 2.6.2973 to Craft CMS 2.6.2981 I get the following error message:
*"Unable to load the "Craft\xyz" runtime after Craft update"*

- "Craft\xyz" is a Twig extension
- Fails in [install folder]\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php line 900 (Twig_Environment::getRuntime())
- Twig_Environment::runtimes is an empty array

Anyone else experienced this problem, and know what is causing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Craft\xyz` a Twig extension coming from a plugin?  Can you try downloading a fresh copy of Craft from https://craftcms.com and replace your existing `craft/app` folder with the fresh one? Would hurt to do the same for the plugin if there is one as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed by changing:**

```
class xyz extends \Twig_Extension
{
    //...
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('kex_cache_breaker', array(__CLASS__, 'cacheBreaker'))
        );
    }
    //...
}
```

**To:**

```
class xyz extends \Twig_Extension
{
    //...
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('kex_cache_breaker', array($this, 'cacheBreaker'))
        );
    }
    //...
}
```